# Each template in meteor looping multiple times

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am learning how to use meteor and when I use the each template the app loops a random number of times.  Does anyone know why?

JS

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');

PlayersList.insert({name: "David" , score:0});
PlayersList.insert({name: "Bob", score: 0});;
PlayersList.insert({name: "Wesley", score: -1000});

if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.leaderboard.helpers({
        player: function(){
            return PlayersList.find();
        }
            });
}
```

and the HTML

```
<head>
    <title>LeaderBoard</title>
</head>

    <body>
        <h1>Leaderboard</h1>

        {{>leaderboard}}
    </body>
    <template name="leaderboard">
        {{#each player}}
            <li>{{name}}: {{score}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </template>
```

Comment: By "random number of times", do you mean: each time you restart/refresh the list grows longer?

Comment: I would suggest, that you wrap the `PlayersList.insert` statements inside an `if (Meteor.isServer)` clause. Otherwise on each load there are Players inserted which might cause your "flickering"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `meteor reset` to clear your database and try this code instead:

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('players');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.leaderboard.helpers({
    player: function() {
      return PlayersList.find();
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    // if there are no players in the database
    if (PlayersList.find().count() === 0) {
      PlayersList.insert({name: "David", score: 0});
      PlayersList.insert({name: "Bob", score: 0});
      PlayersList.insert({name: "Wesley", score: -1000});
    }
  });
}
```

In the original code, players were inserted from both the client and the server (there was no `Meteor.isServer` guard). Every time a new client connected, and every time the server started, a new set of players would be inserted.

In the code above, we only insert new players when the server starts **and** only when there are no players in the database. This ensures the database is only seeded once after a reset.

Comment: also assuming autopublish is still added.